# Gitkraken: Failed initializing Git Flow

Tags: git, git-flow, gitkraken, git-init

I am using Gitkraken to manage my git activities but while initializing Git Flow using inbuilt option provided by Gitkraken it fails.

Here is the screenshot that shows the [image]error message

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Support told me this:

> For now, try deleting your local develop branch and then try initializing GitFlow to work around the issue.

Answer (score 6):

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJU5d.png)

I'm had the same problem, open git bash terminal and run command: "git flow init"
after that open Git kracken and git flow should process normally.

Answer (score 2):

I was have the same issue, and I was solve it run the next command in the root path of project.

```
git-flow init -d
```

if command don't appear in your current bash you can follow the next web pages

[git flow](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/wiki/Install-Bash-git-completion)

[git flow bash completation](https://github.com/bobthecow/git-flow-completion/)

Answer (score 0):

If everything else fails, you can always do this and it should fix the problem:

1. push all your changes/branches to remote in order to avoid loosing them
2. delete the local repository folder
3. re-clone the repository

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue and these are the steps I have followed in order to solve it.

1. Close GitKraken
2. Run GitBash. It should be already installed. In windows 10 use the
   magnifier search - and you should be able to find it.
3. From GitBash select the repository you need to set GitFlow. Hint you
   can use pwd command to see the directory level you are in.Eg mine
   was on C:\source\myrep -my path is-  cd  /c/source/myrep
4. Run the command line git flow init
5. During initialization - you will need to specify the master branch,
   development branch and required flow features. I have left
   everything as a default. Press enter at each request.
6. Restart GitKraken and GitFlow was working.